# I am getting this error "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried everything to get this task done, but nothing works.
This is my code that I have written for web_scraping
The website is some what hierarchical, I am using selenium so that i can see each click is fetching the data.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
ITEM = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

search_url="https://northladder.com/en/ae/electronics/laptop/dell/g-series/v1/5e2c888401c848ac4f695c87"
driver.get(search_url)

clickable = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='select-box-main align-items-center']/label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
n = len(clickable)
for i in range(n):
    items =[]
    items.append(clickable[i].text)
    clickable[i].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    generation = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
    g1 = len(generation)
    for g in range(g1):
        gen = []
        gen.append(generation[g].text)
        generation[g].click()
        time.sleep(2)
        ram = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
        r1 = len(ram)
        for r in range(r1):
            ram_list= []
            ram_list.append(ram[r].text)
            gen.append(ram_list)
            ram[r].click()
            time.sleep(2)
            model = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
            m1 = len(model)
            for m in range(m1):
                model_list = []
                model_list.append(model[m].text)
                ram_list.append(model_list)
                model[m].click()
                screensize= driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
                s1 = len(screensize)
                for s in range(s1):
                    screen_list= []
                    screen_list.append(screensize[s].text)
                    ram_list.append(screen_list)
                    screensize[s].click()
                    memory = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
                    mm1 = len(memory)
                    for mm in range(mm1):
                        memory_list =[]
                        memory_list.append(memory[mm].text)
                        screen_list.append(memory_list)
                        ITEM.append(items)
                        print(ITEM)
```

THis is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.115)
```

Please suggest me something

Comment: selenium doesn't give real object but references to objects in browser memory - and when you `click()` then it loads new objects and this change objects in browser memory and later references can't access previous objects. If you click links then you have to get all links as strings and use `get(url)` instead of `click()`. OR before every click you may have to use alway `find_elements()` to get new reference to objects in memory.

Comment: in all for-loops you use the same `"//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']"` so it always search all links - starting at `core`. You should use relative `xpath` to search - only generations, or only `ram`. You could use `print()` to see what you really get with current xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium doesn't give real object but references to objects in browser memory - and when you `click()` then it loads new objects and this change objects in browser memory and later references can't access previous objects.

If you would click links to new pages sthen you have to get all links as strings and use `get(url)` instead of `click()`.

In other situation you may need to use alway find_elements() before every `click()` (to get again correct references) and use index to get next element.

---

I see other problem - in all `for`-loops you use the same absolute xpath `"//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']"` so it always search all elements - starting at `processers`. You should use relative xpath to search only generations, or only ram, etc.. You could use print() to see what you really get with current xpath.

In this code I always search first all sections with labels

```
sections = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="select-common-wrap"]')
```

and later I use relative xpath (staring with `dot` - `.//`) to search only in selected section

```
generation = sections[1].find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
```

---

**EDIT:**

When item is clicked then it scroll page down and it hides top sections (processor, generation) and later Chrome has problem to click this hidden elements - so I added `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", processor[i])` instead of `processor[i].click()`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
#from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

search_url = "https://northladder.com/en/ae/electronics/laptop/dell/g-series/v1/5e2c888401c848ac4f695c87"
driver.get(search_url)
time.sleep(3)

ALL_ITEMS = []
item = ["", "", "", "", "", ""]
#item = {"processor": "", "generation": "", ...}

# ---

sections = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="select-common-wrap"]')
processor = sections[0].find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
print('processor:', len(processor), '|', [x.text for x in processor])

for i in range(len(processor)):
    item[0] = processor[i].text

    #processor[i].click()
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", processor[i])
    
    time.sleep(2)

    sections = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="select-common-wrap"]')
    generation = sections[1].find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
    print('generation:', len(generation), '|', [x.text for x in generation])

    for g in range(len(generation)):
        item[1] = generation[g].text

        #generation[g].click()
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", generation[g])
        time.sleep(2)

        sections = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="select-common-wrap"]')
        ram = sections[2].find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
        print('ram:', len(ram), '|', [x.text for x in ram])

        for r in range(len(ram)):
            item[2] = ram[r].text

            #ram[r].click()
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", ram[r])
            time.sleep(2)

            sections = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="select-common-wrap"]')
            model = sections[3].find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
            print('model:', len(model), '|', [x.text for x in model])

            for m in range(len(model)):
                item[3] = model[m].text

                #model[m].click()
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", model[m])
                time.sleep(2)

                sections = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="select-common-wrap"]')
                screensize = sections[4].find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
                print('screensize:', len(screensize), '|', [x.text for x in screensize])

                for s in range(len(screensize)):
                    item[4] = screensize[s].text

                    #screensize[s].click()
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", screensize[s])
                    time.sleep(2)

                    sections = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="select-common-wrap"]')
                    drive = sections[5].find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//label/div[@class='select-item m-1']")
                    print('drive:', len(drive), '|', [x.text for x in drive])

                    for d in range(len(drive)):
                        item[5] = drive[d].text

                        ALL_ITEMS.append(item.copy())  # duplicate `item` because I will use the same list to get new results
                        print(item)

for item in ALL_ITEMS:
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
['Core i7', '10th Gen', '32 GB', 'G7', '17 Inch', '1 TB SSD']
['Core i7', '10th Gen', '16 GB', 'G5', '17 Inch', '512 GB SSD']
['Core i7', '10th Gen', '16 GB', 'G3 3500', '15 Inch', '1 TB + 256 GB SSD']
['Core i7', '9th Gen', '16 GB', 'G7 E1297', '15 Inch', '1 TB + 256 GB SSD']
['Core i7', '9th Gen', '16 GB', 'G5 5590', '15 Inch', '1 TB + 512 GB SSD']
['Core i7', '9th Gen', '16 GB', 'G5 5590', '15 Inch', '1 TB + 256 GB']
['Core i7', '9th Gen', '16 GB', 'G5 5590', '15 Inch', '1 TB']
['Core i7', '9th Gen', '16 GB', 'G3 3590', '15 Inch', '512 GB']
['Core i7', '9th Gen', '16 GB', 'G3 3590', '15 Inch', '1 TB + 256 GB SSD']
['Core i7', '8th Gen', '16 GB', 'G5 5587', '15 Inch', '1 TB + 256 GB SSD']
['Core i7', '8th Gen', '16 GB', 'G3 3579', '15 Inch', '256 GB']
['Core i7', '8th Gen', '16 GB', 'G3 3579', '15 Inch', '1 TB + 512 GB SSD']
['Core i7', '8th Gen', '8 GB', 'G3 3579', '15 Inch', '1 TB']
['Core i5', '10th Gen', '16 GB', 'G3 3500', '15 Inch', '1 TB + 256 GB SSD']
['Core i5', '10th Gen', '8 GB', 'G3 3500', '15 Inch', '256 GB SSD']
['Core i5', '8th Gen', '8 GB', 'G3 3579', '15 Inch', '1 TB']
```

Comment: I really need these outputs. but I am getting this error

Comment: `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <div class="select-item m-1"> is not clickable at point (593,61) because another element <a href="/en/ae/testimonials"> obscures it
Stacktrace`

Comment: Any idea why am I getting this error

Comment: do you see browser when you run code? Maybe it displays some `message dialog` (like message about cookies) which hides element and it can't click it. You may have to first close this message

Comment: please help me out @furas

Comment: No i can't see, do i need to do some settings?

Comment: in Firefox it doesn't make problem but in Chrome when it opens new section then it scrolls page down and top sections (processor, generation) are hidden and it can't click top section. It may need to scroll page to top to show again top sections (processor, generation)

Comment: eventually you can use javascript to click it - like `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", processor[i])` instead of `processor[i].click()`

Comment: I added this to current code in answer

Answer (score 1):

### DOM Issue:

This probably to do with the *element not being attached to the DOM*. See [Selenium Docs](https://www.selenium.dev/exceptions/#stale_element_reference) on this error.

> A common technique used for simulating a tabbed UI in a web app is to prepare DIVs for each tab, but only attach one at a time, storing the rest in variables. In this case, it's entirely possible that your code might have a reference to an element that is no longer attached to the DOM (that is, that has an ancestor which is document.documentElement).

> If WebDriver throws a stale element exception in this case, even though the element still exists, the reference is lost. You should discard the current reference you hold and replace it, possibly by locating the element again once it is attached to the DOM.

Your use of **.click() commands changes the DOM structure** of the webpage. Make sure you *re-establish your variables* after every DOM change to have the element be a part of the current DOM structure so that you can interact with the elements.